# Adding CSS Class to client side hyperlink on code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, css, page-lifecycle

I have a list of links :

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Aktuel</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Business</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Common</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Extras</a></li>
</ul>
```

I have to add a css class to one of the links. I will have to do it in codebehind with C#. 
The result should be something like this :

```
....
<li><a href="#" class="active">Business</a></li>
....
```

On which life cycle event should I do it and how?

Note : I cant change the html design.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: probably best will be to render .js that updates to class. How do you know which link to append the class to though?

Comment: If the parent element of the `<ul/>` is not labeled with runat server or you cant modify the `<ul/>` with a `runat="server"` attribute you are out of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register a ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript on the CodeBehind, to run a jQuery script and do the job.

**Complete solution, including the ASP.NET bit:**

```
string jsScript = "$(function () { $(\"a:contains('Aktuel')\").addClass(\"active\"); });";

ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "anythingYouFancy", jsScript, true);
```

You can check it working here (not the ASP.NET part tough):

http://jsfiddle.net/JwkAe/

Comment: I have tried. It writes the script on the page but it does not add the class. Should I also add sth to get it executed?

Comment: Did you add the jQuery library aswell? Also, have a look at my update. I've missed a bit.

Comment: Ok. It should work. I think I have to play around a bit to find the mistake.